# Edit app in order to support both IOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, xcode

I had an app that worked with IOS7 now if I change the deployment target to IOS8 I get lot of Deprecated Methods, I want to edit the app in order to work for boht IOS versions, should I keep deployment target to IOS7 and change every deprecated method for IOS8?

Comment: yes man, you can do like this, if you will change ur deployment target to ios8, then ios7 users not able to download ur app.

Comment: The `deployment` target is the lowest version of iOS that is supported by your app. Setting it to iOS 8 make your app unavailable for devices running iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing deployment target will not work.
Please keep deployment target to the lowest supported iOS version.

Also, Apple provides backward compatibility. So the deprecated methods will work.
For best result use `respondsToSelector` .

Try to replace deprecated methods but with caution. Keep your old methods as is. And conditionally give support for iOS 8 and above.

Hope i am helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Ok so maybe I'll check if the device runs IOS8 or IOS7 and change the method, thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Either you can check for OS version or use respondsToSelector. If it doesn't respond to the selector provide your alternate method.

To find os vesrion:
#define systemVersion [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]

Answer (score 0):

If you intend support iOS 7. Set your Deployment Target to 7.0

Within your build settings, make sure that the Base SDK is at least 8.0 (the latest version you want to support) or typically most people will select Latest iOS which will list the latest version that the SDK would support. Currently iOS 8.1.

Deprecated Methods are referring to methods that are outdated BUT they still work because Apple provides backward compatibility. It is just a friendly warning. In the sense of, "Hey you don't need these older methods anymore since you're just supporting iOS 8. There's newer ways to do things in town."

In your case, change deployment target back to 7.0 and if you want to (optional), go ahead and update any remaining deprecated methods that are probably left from iOS 6, iOS 5, etc etc.